# What should be the redirect_uri when using Yammer in Win 8 App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, yammer

I am creating a Windows Store App which would let users authenticate using Yammer.
I am not sure what do I put my redirect_uri so as the service redirects to my app after authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the relevant topic in the official documentation on Yammer API [Yammer Mobile](http://developer.yammer.com/mobile/).
There is also a sample project in [windows phone oath demo](https://github.com/yammer/windows-phone-oauth-sdk-demo)